# PHP map array1 keys to array 2 indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, offset, columnsorting

I'm trying to take the results of one array and replace them in a different array when the indexes don't match up. I've tried all the usual stuff and can't seem to figure it out.

```
$keysArray = array("Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", "Header 4", "Header 5", "Header 6", "Header 7", "Header 8");
$resultsArray = array("Result 1", "Result 2", "Result 3", "Result 4", "Result 5");
[Keys] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 2
        )

[Results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Result 1 (Belongs in Keys Array [1])
                    [1] => Result 2 (Belongs in Keys Array [3])
                    [2] => Result 3 (Belongs in Keys Array [7])
                    [3] => Result 4 (Not in Keys)
                    [4] => Result 5 (Belongs in Keys Array [4])
                    [5] => Result 6 (Not in Keys)
                    [6] => Result 7 (Not in Keys)
                    [7] => Result 8 (Not in keys)
                 )
        )
```

Code to this point goes something like...

```
$result = array_intersect($keysArray, $resultsArray);
foreach($result as $k=>$r) {
    if($r == "Result 1") {
        $result1 = $r;
    }
    if($r == "Result 2") {
        $result2 = $r;
    }
        // etc., etc., etc.
}
```

"Keys" array is set in a specific order (to match DB table). What I'm trying to do is take data from other sources and map it to the correct order. The "Results" array is one example of the source data. Kind of like parsing tabular data and putting it into the correct field.

Comment: Please explain better how you go form array Result (which is your source ?!?) to array Key (hwihc is your target ?!?).  Debugging your code is impossible if your algorithm is not clearly defined in the question.

Comment: Pretty sure this would need to be `[4] => 3` in your keys array, for this to start making sense ...? But what actual result you want to get here, is still not really clear. Do you want to insert this data _into_ "Keys", or is that just a helper array ...?

Comment: @CBroe... edited to reflect mistake you mentioned.

 The [Keys] array is a preformatted array of headers. I have other code that goes through various results sources (lists, arrays, etc.) and matches their headers with the headers from the [Keys] array. It then finds which result belongs to which key. I can get the actual numbers from the [Results] key, but not the actual results "Result 1" etc.

Hope that helps it make more sense.

Comment: Still unclear what end result you are trying to get here. Are you trying to fill the values _into_ `keys`, are you trying to create a new result array that contains one item for each of the `results`, ...?

Comment: @CBroe... added more info in hopes it assists in understanding what I'm trying to do. I have an established format (Keys) in a specific order. I take data from other sources and try to match it to where it fits in the Keys order. If it matches, I want to get the Result mapped to the Key it belongs to (Result[0] = Keys[1], etc.).

If these were tables, it would be like selecting a Results column where the header matches a column header in the Keys table and mapping it to that. From there, I would like to create a new array that maps the actual Result to the Key and display it.

Comment: No, it makes even less sense now. Your initial `[Keys]` had no values in most places, and a specific _numeric_ value in others, the latter indicating where the data from the results should be inserted. `$keysArray` looks to be something structurally significantly now. And `$result = array_intersect($keysArray, $resultsArray);` would result in a completely empty `$result` array with that given input data, so what would you even attempt to loop over with that foreach after.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My [Keys] array is fixed in format and count limits and my [Results] array was not, so the [Results] wouldn't necessarily line up. For my above example, [Keys] => [1] is equiavlent to [Results] => [0] so I used bindParam to affix the result to the proper key depending on where it fell in my [Keys] array. Now, when I print/echo/etc., it displays in the correct location.

```
$stmt->bindParam( 1, $result1);
$stmt->bindParam( 2, $result2);
$stmt->bindParam( 3, $result3);
$stmt->bindParam( 4, $result4);
$stmt->bindParam( 5, $result5);
```

Thank you to those who responded. I know it wasn't easy to decipher what I was trying to do.